# Ask for 2 inputs inside menu

Tags: python

I'm stuck on some of my school work. I need to create a 2 player rock paper scissors game(playerOne, cpu) the cpu needs to use random number generator. My problem is I don't know how to have the program ask for a second input from the menu.

```
        menuChoice= eval(input("Enter your choice here: "))
        if menuChoice == 1:
            subTotal += PIZZA_PRICE
            #display subTotal
```

thats the example i'm guiding off but it's only for one input.

```
while subMenuOne != 4:
  #Prompt for playerOne subMenuOne choice

  #prompt for cpu subMenuchoice

     if subMenuOne == 1:
        playerOne = Rock
        cpu = Rock
     if (playerOne == cpu):
        #draw
        print("It's a draw. You get to fight another day..")

    elif (playerOne == "Rock" and cpu == "Scissors" or
          playerOne == "paper" and cpu == "rock" or
          playerOne == "scissors" and cpu == "paper"):
             #win
             print("You Won!")
    else:
             #lose
             print("You're Dead. Better Luck Next Time")
```

How can I make the program ask for 2 values so it can figure out the outcome. also for the CPU choice I was told to use this:

```
#random number generator
from random import randrange
def main():
    #randomNumber as integer
    #generate a random number from 1 to 3
    randomNumber = randrange(1,4)
    print (randomNumber)
```

Am I on the right track at least with the other statements in the code? Thanks for the help.

edit: here's what i have so far if anyone wants to take a look. 
http://pastebin.com/fhdgVYG9

Comment: Why do you want two user inputs? Your problem is unclear

Comment: the one player game should include randomly choice by computer(2choices?)  and I have to do a 2 player mode that asks for 2 inputs playerOne playerTwo.

Comment: Ok. Clarification. Shouldn't it be __1__ input from player and other choice is the computer's. Why do you want to make the program "ask for 2 values so it can figure out the outcome". What does that mean? Can you maybe include some pseudocode of what you want it to look like?

Comment: yes sorry, it's 1 input from player and other choice is the computer's.  Then I also need a 2 player mode so input from player one then input from player 2. I didn't want to include that because maybe I could figure it out after getting some help on first part(input from player then input from computer(2 inputs?)) thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that using the `random` module and specifically the `choice` method for the computer part. For the player part, you can keep asking for input until the input is valid. Here is a bit of the code to get you started:

```
from random import choice

player_input = ''
options = ['rock','paper','scissors']

while player_input.lower() not in options: #keep repeating while player response is not a valid option
    player_input = str(raw_input('Please enter valid input: ')).lower()

computer_guess = choice(options)

... #Here you run the comparisons similar to as you have shown in the code above.
#Except, make sure all the string comparisons you make are in lowercase
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm so new at programming that even this is beyond me :( would I have to rewrite my whole code, to be honest I wouldn't know where to input this or how to change my code.

Comment: @user3320792, This is the start of the code as it is. You only have to add the checking logic of who wins and what not after the code that I have provided and you should be fine. Please take note of the comment in the last line of my answer

Comment: this is link to code http://pastebin.com/fhdgVYG9 don't know if it be too much for you just to edit one of them then i can see what you're doing.

Comment: @user3320792, Your code is really confusing to understand for me. I suggest you take the code I have provided above, add a `print` statement at the end of the code to print the `player_input` and `computer_guess` values and paste the code into a __separate__ file and run it and see how it goes. That way you will understand what is happening and will be able to improve your own code much better than if I spent hours figuring out the code that you have written so far. Sorry if that was a bit of a let down.

Comment: @user3320792, Was my answer at least slightly helpful to give you a start? If you have any other questions, go ahead.